# transition in different time in Solar2D (ex-CoronaSDK)

Tags: time, lua, transition, coronasdk, solar2d

Is there a way to prevent the characters starting at the same time? I tried this but every single character still starts the action the moment the animation starts even if I added the delay.

```
--runningPG1.. runningPG5 have attached a sprite and coordinates
arrayPg = {runningPG1, runningPG2, runningPG3, runningPG4, runningPG5}

for key, value in pairs(arrayPg) do 
    transition.to(value, { y = value.y+350, time = 1500})
    transition.to(value, { x = value.x-740, time = 2500, delay = 1550 })
    transition.to(value, { y = value.y+825, time = 2500, delay = 4100 })
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want each one to start at a different time, I think you would need to add a delay based on the number in the loop. Something like:

```
--runningPG1.. runningPG5 have attached a sprite and coordinates
arrayPg = {runningPG1, runningPG2, runningPG3, runningPG4, runningPG5}

baseDelay = 0
for key, value in pairs(arrayPg) do 
    transition.to(value, { y = value.y+350, time = 1500, delay = baseDelay })
    transition.to(value, { x = value.x-740, time = 2500, delay = baseDelay + 1550 })
    transition.to(value, { y = value.y+825, time = 2500, delay = baseDelay + 4100 })
    baseDelay = baseDelay + 500
end
```

or you could use a random delay also

```
for key, value in pairs(arrayPg) do 
    baseDelay = math.random(0, 2000)
    transition.to(value, { y = value.y+350, time = 1500, delay = baseDelay })
    transition.to(value, { x = value.x-740, time = 2500, delay = baseDelay + 1550 })
    transition.to(value, { y = value.y+825, time = 2500, delay = baseDelay + 4100 })
end
```